# NestJS Typeorm Subscriber afterUpdate event not returning updated columns

Tags: nestjs, entity, typeorm, subscriber

I have a Typeorm subscriber which listens to all entity actions.
For `afterUpdate`, the event has these properties.

```
export interface UpdateEvent<Entity> {
    /**
     * Connection used in the event.
     */
    connection: DataSource;
    /**
     * QueryRunner used in the event transaction.
     * All database operations in the subscribed event listener should be performed using this query runner instance.
     */
    queryRunner: QueryRunner;
    /**
     * EntityManager used in the event transaction.
     * All database operations in the subscribed event listener should be performed using this entity manager instance.
     */
    manager: EntityManager;
    /**
     * Updating entity.
     */
    entity: ObjectLiteral | undefined;
    /**
     * Metadata of the entity.
     */
    metadata: EntityMetadata;
    /**
     * Updating entity in the database.
     */
    databaseEntity: Entity;
    /**
     * List of updated columns. In query builder has no affected
     */
    updatedColumns: ColumnMetadata[];
    /**
     * List of updated relations. In query builder has no affected
     */
    updatedRelations: RelationMetadata[];
}
```

Guessing `updatedColumns` would return an array of updated column names, but it is returning `empty array [ ]`.

Any idea how to get which columns were updated

Comment: are you using query builder to update? If yes, then as per docs you won't get data in that key. 
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/subscriber/event/UpdateEvent.ts

Comment: No. I have used `update` function